# Select the distinct latest 2 rows based on the timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below. I want to extract the latest(based on time) 2 rows having same id. If no rows are same do not return anything. Then subtract the values of the latest row with the second latest and return a table with the ID and the value result.

Below is the table. 1st column is the id. Second is the value, third is the time. Id is not primary or unique

```
Id value  time
3   2   2019-01-11 18:59:07.403
2   7   2019-01-10 18:58:40.400
4   5   2019-01-12 18:58:42.400
2   2   2019-01-11 18:59:23.147
5   -5  2019-01-12 18:58:42.400
3   8   2019-01-12 18:59:27.670
2   5   2019-01-12 18:59:43.777
```

The result should be

```
id  value
2   3
3   6
```

Comment: "...extract the latest(based on time) 2 rows having same id..." Can you explain this? Is it the last two rows, or the ones that have the same id?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution uses aggregation to get the IDs which occur more than once and correlated subqueries with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to get the latest and second latest value.

```
SELECT x.id,
       (SELECT t.value
               FROM elbat t
               WHERE t.id = x.id
               ORDER BY t.time DESC
               LIMIT 0, 1)
       -
       (SELECT t.value
               FROM elbat t
               WHERE t.id = x.id
               ORDER BY t.time DESC
               LIMIT 1, 1) value
       FROM (SELECT t.id
                    FROM elbat t
                    GROUP BY t.id
                    HAVING count(*) > 1) x;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d68b559a3c88ee6cade55acd03ba968)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions and conditional aggregation

```
select t.id,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then value else - value end) as diff
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc) as seqnum             
      from elbat t
     ) t
where seqnum in (1, 2)
group by id
order by max(time) desc
limit 2;
```

The same idea can be adapted to earlier versions, using variables:

```
select t.id,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then value else - value end) as diff
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@i = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@i := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             )  as seqnum             
      from (select t.* from elbat t order by id, time desc) t cross join
           (select @i := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where seqnum in (1, 2)
group by id
order by max(time) desc
limit 2;
```